# Generic code for clicking web element from a list in Python:

Tags: python, selenium, automation

**Here is my code in Java that I want to convert in Python:**

```
public static void clickElementFromList(String ListObject, String strname) 
{
    List<WebElement> wbeElement;

    wbeElement = Util.findElements(ListObject);

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < wbeElement.size(); cnt++) 
    {
        if (wbeElement.get(cnt).getText().trim().contentEquals(strname)) 
        {
            wbeElement.get(cnt).click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

//listobj is the web element.
//strname is the displayed text in the application

Comment: Just try it yourself and share what you have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we are not translators..

If you want to translate java code to python you have to translate it manually. It looks like there are some tools out e.g. [java2python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/java2python) but the author states

> The generated Python code is not guaranteed to run, nor is guaranteed
>   to be syntactically valid Python.

If you simply want to use a java library in a application that you want to write in python you could give [jython](http://www.jython.org/) a try.

But as per your question and requirement to give you example/sample or a hint..

First find all elements of list according to your condition by!

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
# here find method will have to modified according to your condition of getting webElements
list = browser.find()
```

Then as per your requirement of method try something like this:

```
def clickElementFromList(list_object, strname):
    for name in list_object:
        text = name.text
        if text is not None:
            if text == strname:
                name.click()
                break
```

Then call function:

```
clickElementFromList(your list here, strname here)
```

Hope this will help you! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will integrate this and let you know about the results.

Comment: @SagnikSarkar: Welcome! Yeah Sure that will be great!

Comment: Actually that name has no attribute as text. How to get the text out of the element?